# How could I remove a whole block of unwanted text using Unix grep?

Tags: unix, grep

Had been trying this hard enough but still couldn't figure out any smarter way to do it...

example:

```
### this is the whole block structure ###
text_text_text
text_text_text
text_text_text
apple
### another block ###
text_text_text
text_text_text
text_text_text
orange
```

Doing `less <file_name> | grep -B3 "apple" | less` will return:

```
text_text_text
text_text_text
text_text_text
apple
```

but now my requirement is I don't want this block (with apple). I am sure about what I do not want, but not certain about what I want. So I could't do this

```
less <file_name> | grep -B3 "orange" |less
```

if I were to:

```
less <file_name> | grep -v "apple" | less
```

then only the single line with apple is removed, the block related to apple will be remaining there.

and I tried

```
less <file_name> | grep -v -B3 "apple" | less
```

but that doesn't seem working.

So any way to help me remove that block related to apple?

Comment: Using `less` instead of `cat` doesn't really get you out of a charge of UUOC — Useless Use of `cat`. You should be using `grep ... <file_name> | less`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to remove the *unwanted block* would be to use `tac` and `sed`.  Saying:

```
tac <filename> | sed '/apple/,+3d' | tac
```

would return:

```
### this is the whole block structure ###
### another block ###
text_text_text
text_text_text
text_text_text
orange
```

for your sample data.

---

Explanation: `tac` reverses lines in a file.  `/apple/,+3` would match `apple` and the next 3 lines.  `d` is the `delete` command.

Since you need to remove the pattern `apple` and 3 lines before it; we reverse the lines in the files, find `apple`, delete it and the next 3 lines, and reverse the lines again to get the desired result.

You might also want to refer to the [`sed manual`](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks and I find your way maybe useful to me. I might need to modify some more though to get my final intended output.

But can you explain me why the ,+3d is there? I wanted to fully understand this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: @user2919338 Added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: This does not work if there is another block above `apple` block

Comment: @Jotne Did you try it?  Can you present an example?  Seems to work for the OP, though.  (BTW, there is enough explanation in the answer above to convey how this works.)

Comment: Try to add a block above your `apple` block like this `### anoter block ###
text_text_text
text_text_text
text_text_text
banan
### this is the whole block structure ###
text_text_text
text_text_text
text_text_text
apple
### another block ###
text_text_text
text_text_text
text_text_text
orange`

Comment: @Jotne Works for me with your sample text.  I'm using `GNU sed`, BTW.

Comment: With your code, i does not delete block complete, it leaves the line `### this is the whole block structure ###`

Comment: @Jotne Since I'm not the OP, I can only _guess_: (1) those lines were intended as markers, (2) it was clearly stated that a __certain number__ of lines before (and including) the pattern need to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` and assuming every block is 5 records long.

```
cat file
### anoter block ###
text_text_text
text_text_text
text_text_text
banan
### this is the whole block structure ###
text_text_text
text_text_text
text_text_text
apple
### another block ###
text_text_text
text_text_text
text_text_text
orange
```

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0} /apple/ {f=NR} END {for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) if (i<f-4 || i>f) print a[i]}'
### anoter block ###
text_text_text
text_text_text
text_text_text
banan
### another block ###
text_text_text
text_text_text
text_text_text
orange
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk '/^apple$/{cs=0;next} 
           { c[cs++]=$0 }
    cs > 3 {
       print c[0];
       for (i=0;i<3;i++){c[i]=c[i+1]}; cs--;
    }
    END    { for (i=0;i<cs;i++){print c[i]} }' input
```